# How to get protocol parameters **only for latest epoch** with GraphQL?

Tags: cardano-graphql, shelley

How can I get protocol parameters *only for the latest epoch* using GraphQL?

I can get protocol parameters with cardano-cli:

```
cardano-cli query protocol-parameters \
  --testnet-magic 1097911063 \
  --out-file $HOME/cardano/protocol.json
```

I can get protocol parameters for multiple epochs with help of this query

https://github.com/input-output-hk/cardano-graphql/blob/master/packages/api-cardano-db-hasura/src/example_queries/epochs/epochProtocolParams.graphql

Answer (score 1):

I've found the solution:

```
query currentEpochProtocolParams {
  cardano {
    currentEpoch {
      number
      protocolParams {
        a0
        coinsPerUtxoWord
        collateralPercent
        costModels
        decentralisationParam
        eMax
        extraEntropy
        keyDeposit
        maxBlockBodySize
        maxBlockExMem
        maxBlockExSteps
        maxBlockHeaderSize
        maxCollateralInputs
        maxTxExMem
        maxTxExSteps
        maxTxSize
        maxValSize
        minFeeA
        minFeeB
        minPoolCost
        minUTxOValue
        nOpt
        poolDeposit
        priceMem
        priceStep
        protocolVersion
        rho
        tau
      }
    }
  }
}
```